# How do i extract the string when using props.location.query in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, react-props

Below is how I obtain a string sent from another component. What i am trying to achieve is to be able to store the below string in a variable. For example `var string1` should obtain `"user1"` and not `{query:"user1"}`

```
var string1 = this.props.location.query); 

console.log(string1);
```

when the console log executes the below data appears which is the correct data i am meant to retrieve.

```
{query: "user1"}
```

Comment: from the limited information you have provided, it appears that the value is an object, not a string.  try `this.props.location.query.query`.  if that doesn't work, show us the value of this.props.location

Comment: @jdigital thanks thats what i wanted was unsure what to include in this post, if u want you can post the above as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the value is an object, not a string. try `this.props.location.query.query`

`this.props` presumably looks something like this:

```
{ props:
    { location:
        { query:
            { query: "user1" }
        }
    }
}
```